# Revival badge description typo

Tags: feature-request, badges, grammar

> "Answered more than 30 days later as first answer scoring 2 or more.
>   This badge can be awarded multiple times."

Should it maybe be:

> Answered more than 30 days later than the first answer, scoring 2 or
>   more. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

.. or maybe:

> Answered a question more than 30 days after the first answer and
>   achieved a score of 2 or more. This badge can be awarded multiple
>   times

Tricky getting it concise and clear. It's definitely grammatically incorrect and unclear as it is now.

Comment: Not to nit-pick, but a "typo" is when something isn't typed as intended, e.g. hitting the wrong key...this is more about the grammar/clarity of the description :)

Answer (score 4):

The answer that gets the badge must be an answer given 30 days after the question was posted, and the first answer of that question to get to a score of two or more.  I agree that this is very confusing.

It's a bit clearer on [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68258#68258)

> Revival
>
> - bronze; awarded multiple times
> - Answer a question 30 days after it is asked and have that answer be the first one for that question to reach a score of two

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit old, but I'd like to see if this can be revisited.  Rather than posting a duplicate topic, I've opted to post an answer with my suggestion, because I was a little confused on the text when I saw it.

> Answered more than 30 days later as first answer scoring 2 or more. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

I didn't know anything about the [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68258#68258) until I found this thread, so the only description I had to go on was the quoted text above.

I'd like to suggest that the mini-text be changed to

> Answered more than 30 days later as **the** first answer **to score** 2 or more. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

(changes are **bolded** to mark the differences from the current text).

Comment: I agree. I found the description of this badge a bit confusing too.